# Cypher - Neo4j Query Profiling

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have some questions regarding Neo4j's Query profiling. 
Consider below simple Cypher query:

```
PROFILE 
MATCH (n:Consumer {mobileNumber: "yyyyyyyyy"}),
      (m:Consumer {mobileNumber: "xxxxxxxxxxx"}) 
WITH n,m 
MATCH (n)-[r:HAS_CONTACT]->(m) 
RETURN n,m,r;
```

and output is:

[image]

So according to [Neo4j's Documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/execution-plans/expand-operators/#query-plan-expand-into):

> 3.7.2.2. Expand Into
>
> When both the start and end node have already been found, expand-into
>   is used to find all connecting relationships between the two nodes.
>
> Query.
>
> ```
> MATCH (p:Person { name: 'me' })-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(fof)-->(p) RETURN
> > fof
> ```

So here in the above query (in my case), first of all, it should find both the StartNode & the EndNode before finding any relationships. But unfortunately, it's just finding the StartNode, and then going to expand all connected `:HAS_CONTACT` relationships, which results in not using "Expand Into" operator. Why does this work this way? There is only one `:HAS_CONTACT` relationship between the two nodes. There is a Unique Index constraint on `:Consumer{mobileNumber}`. Why does the above query expand all 7 relationships?

Another question is about the **Filter** operator: why does it requires 12 db hits although all nodes/ relationships are already retrieved? Why does this operation require 12 db calls for just 6 rows?

### Edited

This is the complete Graph I am querying:
[image: Graph Data]

Also I have tested different versions of same above query, but the same Query Profile result is returned:

### 1

```
PROFILE
 MATCH (n:Consumer{mobileNumber: "yyyyyyyyy"})
 MATCH (m:Consumer{mobileNumber: "xxxxxxxxxxx"}) 
 WITH n,m 
 MATCH (n)-[r:HAS_CONTACT]->(m) 
 RETURN n,m,r;
```

### 2

```
PROFILE
 MATCH (n:Consumer{mobileNumber: "yyyyyyyyy"}), (m:Consumer{mobileNumber: "xxxxxxxxxxx"}) 
 WITH n,m 
 MATCH (n)-[r:HAS_CONTACT]->(m) 
 RETURN n,m,r;
```

### 3

```
PROFILE 
MATCH (n:Consumer{mobileNumber: "yyyyyyyyy"}) 
WITH n 
MATCH (n)-[r:HAS_CONTACT]->(m:Consumer{mobileNumber: "xxxxxxxxxxx"}) 
RETURN n,m,r;
```

Comment: Could you post some data here to allow us to better understand your graph? This may - and this is a little bit of a guess based on experience - to do with the query planner trying to reduce the load created by producing a cartesian product (i.e., in the first match clause). Have you tried changing the first part of the query to use two `MATCH` clauses rather than one with a comma?

Comment: @DomWeldon Kindly check the updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you are executing and the example provided in the Neo4j documentation for **Expand Into** are not the same. The example query starts and ends at the same node.

If you want the planner to find both nodes first and see if there is a relationship then you could use `shortestPath` with a length of 1 to minimize the DB hits.

```
PROFILE 
MATCH (n:Consumer {mobileNumber: "yyyyyyyyy"}),
  (m:Consumer {mobileNumber: "xxxxxxxxxxx"}) 
WITH n,m 
MATCH Path=shortestPath((n)-[r:HAS_CONTACT*1]->(m))
RETURN n,m,r;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And as far as Expand Into is concerned, according to documentation: "When both the start and end node have already been found, expand-into is used to find all connecting relationships between the two nodes." So I think it doesn't matter if both start & end nodes are same or not, just you have to find them before expanding, isn't?

Comment: I read that too. I can only expect that it was misunderstood. If you create a dataset that supports a query as in the example (i.e. a cycle) it uses *Expand Into*.

Answer (score 2):

**Why does this do this?**

It appears that this behaviour relates to how the query planner performs a database search in response to your cypher query. Cypher provides an interface to search and perform operations in the graph (alternatives include the Java API, etc.), queries are handled by the query planner and then turned into graph operations by neo4j's internals. It make sense that the query planner will find what is likely to be the most efficient way to search the graph (hence why we love neo), and so just because a cypher query is written one way, it won't necessarily search the graph in the way we imagine it will in our head.

The documentation on this seemed a little sparse (or, rather I couldn't find it properly), any links or further explanations would be much appreciated.

Examining your query, I think you're trying to say this:

*"Find two nodes each with a `:Consumer` label, n and m, with contact numbers x and y respectively, using the `mobileNumber` index. If you find them, try and find a `-[:HAS_CONTACT]->` relationship from `n` to `m`. If you find the relationship, return both nodes and the relationship, else return nothing."*

Running this query in this way requires a cartesian product to be created (i.e., a little table of all combinations of `n` and `m` - in this case only one row - but for other queries potentially many more), and then relationships to be searched for between each of these rows.

Rather than doing that, since a `MATCH` clause must be met in order to continue with the query, neo knows that the two nodes `n` and `m` must be connected via the `-[:HAS_CONTACT]->` relationship if the query is to return anything. Thus, the most efficient way to run the query (and avoid the cartesian product) is as below, which is what your query can be simplified to.

*"Find a node `n` with the `:Consumer` label, and value x for the index `mobileNumber`, which is connected via a `-[:HAS_CONTACT]->` relationshop to a node `m` with the `:Consumer` label, and value y for its proprerty `mobileNumber`. Return both nodes and the relationship, else return nothing."*

So, rather than perform two index searches, a cartesian product and a set of expand into operations, neo performs only one index search, an expand all, and a filter.

You can see the result of this simplification by the query planner through the presence of `AUTOSTRING` parameters in your query profile.

**How to Change Query to Implement Search as Desired**

If you want to change the query so that it *must* use an expand into relationship, make the requirement for the relationship optional, or use explicitly iterative execution. Both these queries below will produce the initially expected query profiles.

Optional example:

```
PROFILE
 MATCH (n:Consumer{mobileNumber: "xxx"})
 MATCH (m:Consumer{mobileNumber: "yyy"}) 
 WITH n,m 
 OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r:HAS_CONTACT]->(m) 
 RETURN n,m,r;
```

Iterative example:

```
PROFILE
 MATCH (n1:Consumer{mobileNumber: "xxx"})
 MATCH (m:Consumer{mobileNumber: "yyy"}) 
 UNWIND COLLECT(n1) AS n
 MATCH (n)-[r:HAS_CONTACT]->(m) 
 RETURN n,m,r;
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But here I can't use OPTIONAL MATCH, because I want to return endNode only in case if given relationship exists in between the 2 nodes + want to find endNode before expanding all relationships just to get rid of unwanted relationships/nodes and to reduce db hits. Also when using 2nd query with UNWIND, it is showing an error saying: "Aggregations should not be used like this."